# Encryption password FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a symfony project using FOSUSerBundle to manage users , Now I need to access to Database via a Simple Rest Webservice ,
The encryption in the registration is : Sha512 , How can i get the same hash result as FOS 
I tried :

```
hash('sha512',($salt.$password));
```

and

```
hash('sha512',($password.$salt));
```

But it doesnt work ! Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to thing class, who encode passwords fos FOSUserBundle, you can understand how Symfony made his encryption

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php

So you will get something like:

```
$password = 'toto';
$salt = '1234';
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

for ($i=1; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, true);
}

$encodedPassword = base64_encode($digest);
```